# How to Create a Timeout In a CRM Workflow That Uses a Static Attribute Value

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow-foundation, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm specifying a timeout in a workflow within CRM against a particular contact attribute (Next Time To Run):

`Timeout until "Contact:Next Time To Run"`

This works great, until someone updates the "Next Time To Run" attribute.  When this happens, CRM re-evaluates the timeout and adjusts it to the new "Next Time To Run" value.  This is what I don't want.  I want the timeout to use the value of the "Next Time To Run" when the workflow was originally triggered (static).  I don't want the timeout to dynamically update based on the attribute changing.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this solution and I believe it solves your problem:

I added an extra field ("Hidden Time To Run") to the entity, a date field that doesn't appear on the form.

Workflow steps:

1. When the workflow is triggered, copy the date from "Next Time To Run" to "Hidden Time To Run".
2. Timeout until "Contact: Hidden Time To Run"

Thus, changing the "Next Time To Run" attribute won't have an effect on when the workflow is expected to run.

Comment: Your solution will work, but I've come up with a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Custom Workflow Activity that adds a configurable amount of time to a date.  I just called the Activity and didn't actually increment it.  It returned a value that was static, and resulted in the timeout being unchanged if the attribute it was based on changed.

Comment: When the workflow triggers and can you post you Custom Workflow Activity logic?

Comment: @Sxntk Do you want the logic because you want to be able to increment a date, or do you want to be able to perform a static value evaluation?

Comment: I want to see what you are doing

Comment: @Sxntk I want to be as clear that I understand what you're asking for.  Do you want to see the workflow activity that will add Months/Days/Hours/Minutes/Seconds to a Date?  Or do you want to see a Code Activity that will return a static DateTime to be used in a workflow?

Comment: I want to see the code activity, what are you passing to the custom  and how you are incrementing the date. If it is possible the workflow but I think we can do something with the custom.